# positive measurable function on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f$ is a positive measurable function on $[0,1]$, which is larger,
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,\log f(x)\,dx \qquad \text{or} \qquad \int_{0}^{1}f(s)\,ds\int_{0}^{1}\log f(t)\,dt$$

Can you help me please?

Comment: Do you know Jensens inequality?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to use the inequality to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a measurable $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[1,\infty)$ we always have,

$$\int_0^1f\cdot \log (f)dx\geq\int_0^1fdy\int_0^1\log (f)dw $$

Proof:

Since $\lambda([0,1])=1$ we can apply Jensens ineqauality. Note that the function $\phi(x)=x\log (x)$ is convex for $x\in(0,\infty)$

On the other hand $\psi(y)=\log (y)$ is concave.

Henca by Jensens inequality,

$$\int_0^1f\cdot \log (f)dx=\int_0^1\phi(f)dx\geq\phi\left(\int_0^1fdx\right)=\int_0^1fdy\cdot \log \left(\int_0^1fdw\right)\geq\int_0^1fdy\int_0^1\log (f)dw$$

What about different $f$?

Comment: You are welcome!